# square formed by the quadratic equations.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Question:A Square is Formed By The Straight Lines $x^2-8 x+12 = 0$ And $ y^2-14y+45 = 0$. What are the coordinates?
How do I solve it? Providing a basic intiution will do the job.
Also the graphs of the equations have been referred  to as straight but shouldn't they be parabolic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Rewrite $-8=(-2+-6)$ and $-14=(-5+-9).$ Distribute the $x$ or $y$ (whichever is relevant) and factor by grouping and solve. This will then give you $4$ straight lines.

Alternately, you can solve the two quadratic equations by completing the square, or using the quadratic formula.

---

In order to be parabolic, you'd need something like $y=x^2-8x+12$ or $x=y^2-14x+45.$

Comment: So does that means ax^2 + bx + c = 0, is a straight line?

Comment: Forgive me for asking but why can't the given equations be functions of the x-axis and y-axis respectively. The parabolas seem to intersect and create a closed shape with 4 distinct points of intersection. I know that it's not a square but please tell me what's wrong with my assumption.

Comment: @shauryagupta: Not necessarily. If $a\neq 0,$ then the solution set (in the plane) to $ax^2+bx+c=0$ is: (i) two straight lines if $b^2-4ac>0$, (ii) one straight line if $b^2-4ac=0$, and (iii) the empty set if $b^2-4ac<0$.

Comment: @Nick: What parabolas? While $x^2-8x+12$ is a function of $x,$ $x^2-8x+12=0$ is *not* a function of $x$. Rather, it is a way of describing two very specific values of $x$.

Comment: @shauryagupta: From what Cameron has said to me, each quadratic equation is merely a representation of it's roots. Therefore, the square is formed by the intersection of the lines made by the roots. (Note that the 2 roots of the second equation are perpendicular to that of the first)

Comment: @CameronBuie: Thank you very much. I realize now the distinction between functions and equations. Textbook exercises seem to have numbed my mind.

Comment: @Nick: You're welcome. They can certainly do that....